# Lock the Nemo icon to the Unity Launcher (Ubuntu 14.04) and customize it

Tags: unity, launcher

Is it possible to create the same kind of shortcuts like the Nautilus launcher has, for the Nemo file browser?

How can I edit Unity Launcher shortcuts in an easy manner, can I use a text editor or GUI editor for this?

Comment: About restoring the nautilus launcher; it depends on what you did to change it. Its contents how it appears comes from different sources.

Comment: Your question exists of quite different sub- subjects (I count at least 4, a lot to say about each). Probably better to split up and look for existing answers first. If they don't exist, ask more specifically.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Narrowing it down my first aim is to have the home folder (of `Nemo` [I replaced the default file manager]) displayed in the `Unity Launcher`.

Comment: Assuming you succeeded in making Nemo your default file browser, does simply open Nemo from Dash and lock it (right-click, "lock to launcher") to the launcher not work? It will be called "Files" as well.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I succeeded in it by following some guides and with trial and error, but it does not simply support right click options for going to different bookmarks as `Nautilus Home Folder` supported.

Comment: I don't use Nemo, but if you drag it from Dash on to the launcher? I just tried installing Nemo on 12.10, and it worked immediately, even could make a few (directory-) shortcuts at once.

Comment: Added my answer to manually add shortcuts to the nemo launcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Nemo does not have the sophisticated integrated bookmark options like Nautilus does, but you can add bookmarks manually.

#### Adding shortcuts to the Nemo launcher icon

To add shortcuts, we need to edit the `nemo.desktop` file.
In the example below, we add the directory `/home/<yourname>/Documents` as a shortcut:

1. Copy the file to your local directory:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/nemo.desktop
   ```
2. open the local `nemo.desktop` file with `gedit`:

   - Browse in your home directory to the file (`~/.local` is hidden by default, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to make it visible)
   - Drag the file over an open `gedit` window.
3. At the end of the file, add a line:

   Actions=Documents;
4. At the (very) end of the file, add the section:

   ```
   [Desktop Action Documents]
   Name=Documents
   Exec=nemo /home/<yourname>/Documents
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```

   (Replace `<yourname>` by your username)

To add more shortcuts, add more items to the line `Actions=` (e.g. `Actions=Documents;Videos;`) and add more shortcut sections as in `[4]`. An example of how it could look (from the `Actions=` line):

```
Actions=Documents;Videos;

[Desktop Action Documents]
Name=Documents
Exec=nemo /home/<yourname>/Documents
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Videos]
Name=Videos
Exec=nemo /home/<yourname>/Videos
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

[image]

After log out / log in, you should see the changes, and the shortcuts should be available.

#### Notes

1. In `.desktop` files, you should not use `~` as a replacement for your home directory, but use absolute paths.
2. To have direct access to the file, you could include a link that opens the `.desktop` file in `gedit` directly. Below an example of the bottom section of the `nemo.desktop` file and an image of how it looks in your quicklist (to use it, replace all occurrences of `jacob` with your username, but that's obvious):

   ```
   Actions=Documents;Videos;divider1;Edit bookmarks;

   [Desktop Action Documents]
   Name=Documents
   Exec=nemo /home/jacob/Documents
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;

   [Desktop Action Videos]
   Name=Videos
   Exec=nemo /home/jacob/Videos
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;

   [Desktop Action Edit bookmarks]
   Name=Edit Bookmarks
   Exec=gedit /home/jacob/.local/share/applications/nemo.desktop
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;

   [Desktop Action divider1]
   Name=........................
   Exec=zenity --info --text 'This is just a divider'
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I am still trying to get it done by the way can I get `Home` written instead of `Files` as in your screenshot? The same thing happened here too. Furthermore, should I stack entries like **[4]** after **[3]**? I also could not get the entries `Documents` and `Videos` as in your example after logging out then in and trying a complete system reboot.

Comment: @Vesnog edited my answer concerning the first part of your question (comment above). What language is your system? The Nemo `.desktop` file has an extensive list of localized names. On my other (Dutch) computer, the appearing name is "Bestanden". Let me know what language your system is. (And if the edit helped you of course).

Comment: The language of the OS is US English.

Comment: @Vesnog Then it is easy, if you have your `.desktop` file opened, change the *second* line (`Name=Files`) into `Name=Home`. `Us English` uses the default name. Do you manage with the Bookmarks?

Comment: I am trying right now, I will keep you updated. By the way do I need to keep the names in all the other languages? I think I can delete them along with `comment` lines to reduce clutter.

Comment: I edited the `nemo.desktop` file and updated my OP accordingly. Now I will log out and log back in before searching for `home` in dash and dragging the icon onto `Unity Launcher`.

Comment: I got it working now, I do not know what I did wrong in my previous attempts.

Comment: @Vesnog looks good. For `neat` editing, I would leave an empty line above and below the `Actions=` line, and between the shortcut sections. I will also add a neat edit shortcut to my answer.

Comment: Thanks you, I appreciate your effort. Can you point me out some reference or tutorial preferably with examples to learn the topic further if possible?

Comment: @Vesnog Added a direct access to the `.desktop` file, to make it comfortably editable on a regular base. I actually don't remember so well where I got the information, most of it during writing a quicklist editor. Like many things: the principle is straightforward, but there are the exceptions you have to deal with that can make it a bit more complicated. I'd suggest playing around. As long as you only edit local copies of the `.desktop` files, things can easily be reverted to default.